# Outputting a certain $_SESSION variable inside a for each loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, cart

Im having an issue with outputting a certain session inside a foreach loop, a session that contains a certain string of characters:

```
function cart(){

    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value){


    }
}
```

doing so `^`, outputs all the sessions, and i want it to output only the sessions that contain the $name `cart_`.

If any of you has an idea on how to do so, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you can always check if is Isset the key you're going to use.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could make use of [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
function cart() { 
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if(strpos($name, 'cart_') !== FALSE) {
             //echo here
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: What does the array structure look like?